# What is the difference between Node.spawn/2 and Process.spawn/1?

Tags: elixir

Seems like they both spawn Erlang process if I pass my local node as the argument for `Node.spawn/2`. Is there anything more to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Process.spawn/1` in the first place.

There are:

- [`Kernel.spawn{1,3}`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#spawn/1), [delegated to](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L851) [`:erlang.spawn`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-1),
- [`Node.spawn{2,3,4,5}`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Node.html#spawn/2), [delegated to](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.3/lib/elixir/lib/node.ex#L167) [`:erlang.{spawn,spawn_opt}`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_opt-2), and
- [`Process.spawn{2,4}`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#spawn/2) [delegated to](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.3/lib/elixir/lib/process.ex#L378) [`:erlang.spawn_opt`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_opt-2).

As I dropped the whole set of links to the documentation of both *Elixir* and *erlang* as well as links to the implementation, you might follow the links and make sure all of them are a semantic sugar to spawn an *erlang* process using native *erlang* call, locally or remotely.

Answer (score 0):

```
spawn_opt(Module, Function, Args, Options), 
spawn_opt(Node, Module, Function, Args, Options)
```

can you spot a difference?
Sure if you specify Node as node() in spawn_opt/ 5 it will be the same as calling spaw_opt/4 but that is not the poin, it is more likely that spawn_opt/4 calls spawn_opt/5 passing it node() as the first arg.